# AmStockChart change colors for whole fields while activate/deactivate one

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have AmStockChart which is initialized by JSON with variable count of fields (usually near 20). I do not set color anywhere now.

By clicking on graph label selected graph disabling and all the others change colors.

Yes, I can set colors for each graphs, but my colors are not as beautiful :)

How can I prevent color switching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem for serial chart by setting [colors](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#colors) option:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    ...
    'colors':["#FF0F00", "#FF6600", "#FF9E01", "#FCD202", "#F8FF01",
          "#B0DE09", "#04D215", "#0D8ECF", "#0D52D1", "#2A0CD0", "#8A0CCF",
          "#CD0D74", "#754DEB", "#DDDDDD", "#999999", "#333333",
          "#000000", "#57032A", "#CA9726", "#990000", "#4B0C25",
          "#FF0F00", "#FF6600", "#FF9E01", "#FCD202", "#F8FF01",
          "#B0DE09", "#04D215", "#0D8ECF", "#0D52D1", "#2A0CD0", "#8A0CCF",
      ],
    ...
});
```

We need more colors in 'colors' than graphs on chart.

For AmSerialChart I use 'color' option for each graph.